# User Action on mobile web push notification

Tags: html, push-notification, service-worker, web-push, service-worker-events

Is it possible to create app-like push notifications for mobile web using service workers ? (for instance, the user can respond to a chat message from the notification)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This tutorial explains Web Push in great details:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/